# Crystal Vs SSRS - Click fields to filter

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

How do we make some fields in Crystal report so when user clicks, whole report is filtered based on that value. How can we achieve same behavior in SSRS. I have some converted reports from crystal to SSRS but some converted reports do not have this behavior and BA wants the same thing in SSRS. Can someone please tell me how to do this in SSRS?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic filtering is not possible in SSRS. What you can do is an action on that field Text box) so that it runs the same report but passes the field as a filter parameter. set the default value of the parameter as -1 or something that the field value cannot possibly be. This is so when the report runs initially, there are no filters. Hope that made sense